# Wordpress get id of image(s) used inside post

Tags: wordpress

I would like to get all IDs of images used **inside** a post.

I know how to get all images attached to a post however I want to retrieve all IDs of attached images that are used inside the post. The only way I can think of is by looking
through the_content -> finding all images used -> get IDs from image URL.

Do you think there is a better and more efficient solution.
Again I repeat (just to make it clear :) I need IDs of images that are used inside the post, which means that they are printed out using the_content() function.

Thank you very much
ion

Answer (score 1):

New Answer:

I inserted an image without adding it to a post and as our discussion it does indeed add it as related to the post via parent_post.

Adding it to the post and saving the draft added no additional rows to my database table.  I did however notice that it has a class of "wp-image-705"  where 705 is the wp_posts record for the image.  Therefore it seems the only way currently is to use get_the_content() put it in a variable and use preg_match_all to parse it out via regular expression.

Comment: yes but this query will bring images used by the post. I want to exclude the ones that are used inside the post. Meaning the ones that have been used inside the content from the editor.

Comment: What's the difference of images used "by" the post and images used "inside" the post?  Are they not the same thing?

Comment: The way I understand in Wordpress 3 you can upload images in a post page but not use them inside the post editor. These images are attached in the post but when you print the_content() are not outputed. I hope this makes it clear.